# How to organise children menu links as tabs in D7?

Tags: routes

I'm using Drupal 7 and now I have a regular dropdown menu like this:

Link 1

- sub-link 1
- sub-link 2

Link 2

But I would like to organize my sub-links as tabs where sub-link 1 and sub-link 2 would  be a content tabs that contain a block content. I tried to use OM Maximenu Modul, it helps to organise parent links as tabs but not sub-links. Could anybody help me in this question?

Comment: So, I've just created a block with tabs jquery and some php code to show certain views in tabs content and attached it to menu item through the modul OM Maximenu. It works but I would like to find the easiest way to attach any block to menu item without modules. Thanks in advance if anybody knows how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of OM Maximenu module I used Views Menu module as it easier and I used it only with purpose to attach views block to only one menu link.